# Join multiple rows from a single table to a single line

Tags: sql

Hoping the way I describe this makes sense.  I'm trying to use multiple Case statements on the same column to output values in the same row but in different fields.  Let's use absence plans as an example.

In my case, I'm trying to audit to ensure all employees are assigned the required 6 different absence plans.  Plans 1, 2, & 3 each have multiple plans that could be assigned to fulfil the requirement. (ex. plan 1a/plan 2a/plan 3a  or plan 1b/plan 2c/plan 3a...)

All of the plans are stored in the same table, and as a result are all being output on different rows.  Where I'm trying to have an output of 1 row flagging if each plan is assigned, this is providing an output where a single person has 6 rows of a single plan showing up as assigned for each row, but all others are not assigned.

```
SELECT (CASE 
   WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType1')
     AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
     ELSE 'Plan1 Missing'
   END) AS [Plan1],
    (CASE 
      WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType2')
      AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
      ELSE 'Plan2 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan2],
    (CASE 
    WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType3')
    AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan3 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan3],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan4%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan4 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan4],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan5%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan5 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan5],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan6%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan6 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan6],
```

Comment: add the tag of the sql language you're using

Comment: you must apply some aggregation function (max, min...) over the data once you are done with the case when, this will let you having everything in one single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT max(s.[Plan1]), max(s.[Plan2]), max(s.[Plan3]),max(s.[Plan4]),max(s.[Plan5]),max(s.[Plan6])
from (
  SELECT (CASE 
   WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType1')
     AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
     ELSE 'Plan1 Missing'
   END) AS [Plan1],
    (CASE 
      WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType2')
      AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
      ELSE 'Plan2 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan2],
    (CASE 
    WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like ('PlanType3')
    AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan3 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan3],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan4%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan4 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan4],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan5%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan5 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan5],
    (CASE
    WHEN Table1.[PlanDescrip] like ('%Plan6%') THEN NULL
    ELSE 'Plan6 Missing'
    END) AS [Plan6],
  ...) s
```

If you group this information by some attribute, add a final group by clause by this field (not seem in your query)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a pain -- it would be much easier to express what is present rather than what is missing.  One method is two levels of `case`, one with a count and one with a string.  Here is another method

```
SELECT NULLIF(MIN(CASE WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like 'PlanType1' AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN 'ZZZ' ELSE 'Plan1 Missing'
                  END), 'ZZZ') AS [Plan1],
       NULLIF(MIN(CASE WHEN Table1.[Plan] Like 'PlanType2' AND [enrectype] = 'ABS' THEN 'ZZZ' ELSE 'Plan2 Missing'
                  END), 'ZZZ') AS [Plan2],
      . . .
```